# Do Ajax from server 1 to server 2 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hi I want to do Ajax request from server 1 to server 2 in JavaScript
Ajax code:

```
function sendGet(path) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            return(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", path, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The chrome returns:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://itaysharon.esy.es/jsdb.php?user=test&pass=1234. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`
I am using pure js and I want to keep it that way.
Is there any way to fix it in js?
Thx

Comment: is CORS enabled in server 2?

Comment: Do you have access of both servers?? Are you permitted to edit files at both end??

Comment: As @mido has already stated, it's more than likely a Cors issue.

Comment: @ItaySharon so you need to allow allow origin at both end to share data between both servers.

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam and how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add below ajax request header at server side to share data over cross domain

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

OR

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <server1 IP or domain name>
```

For your question

```
function sendGet(path) {
    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Origin","your server ip or domain of client server");
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            return(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", path, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: function sendGet(path) {
    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Origin","your server ip or domain of client server");
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            return(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", path, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}